# Constructing a bijection between $S=[1,2]$ and $T=[1,2)$

Tags: real-analysis

I am having a bit of trouble with constructing the biijection here. I know that the bijection has to be a piecewise function with one component being $f(x) = x$ when $x$ does not equal $1/n$. But the other component is a bit more tricky, none pass the horizontal line test. Could the other component be $2/n+2$ or how would I go about figuring that component out?

Comment: Your question title obscures your actual question—$S$ and $T$ are out of context.  Are you trying to find a bijection between $[1,2]$ and $[1,2)$?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am trying to do. Sorry, english isnt my native language.

Comment: No problem.  I took the liberty of editing the question title to declare the variables.

Answer (score 2):

You can construct a bijection from $S$ to $T$ by saying that

$$2\mapsto 1+\frac12\\
1+\frac12\mapsto 1+\frac13\\
1+\frac13\mapsto 1+\frac14\\
\vdots$$

and that $x$ maps to $x$ if $x\notin \{1+\frac1n, n\in\mathbb N\}$

Comment: 1/2 is not in $S$

Comment: Perhaps $1+\frac{1}{n} \mapsto 1+\frac{1}{n+1}$?

Comment: @Nex Fixed it. Thanks. The idea is the same, anyway.

Comment: Map every irrational number to itself.  The rational numbers are countable so we can list the rational numbers in [1, 2], starting with 2.  Then map the nth rational on that list to the n+1 rational.

Comment: @user247327 Sure, that's another way of doing it.

Comment: I like to call this the Infinite Hotel bijection; room $n$ corresponds to $1/n$ ($1+1/n$ here) and the bijection leaves only room 1 vacant.

Comment: So would this be a piecewise function if im writing in function notation? Where one function is f(x) = x and another function is 1+1/n where x=1/n?

Comment: @AggrawalPuja Almost. You're sloppy, though. $x$ is never $\frac1n$.

Answer (score 0):

The usual [*Hilbert hotel*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_paradox_of_the_Grand_Hotel) argument works this way: split $[1,2]$ as $[1,2]\cap\mathbb{Q}$ and its complement. Do nothing on the complement, just leave the elements where they are. Consider that $[1,2]\cap\mathbb{Q}$ is a countable set, and enumerate its elements as $2=q_0, 1=q_1, q_2,q_3,\ldots$. On $[1,2]\cap\mathbb{Q}$, consider the map $\varphi$ that sends $q_k$ into $q_{k+1}$. This is an invertible map between $[1,2]\cap\mathbb{Q}$ and $[1,2\color{red}{)}\cap\mathbb{Q}$.